# Deleting a single registry value in C#

Tags: c#, registry

Is there any way to delete a single registry entry in C#? All the deletion methods will remove the whole subkey rather than a single value.

```
Registry.SetValue(@"My\Reg\Key\Path", "MyValue", null);
```

The above example isn't valid to Microsoft.Win32, but hopefully you see what i'm getting at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the appropriate key in read/write mode and invoke the [`DeleteValue()` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk8b3th2(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var regKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"path\to\subkey",true);
regKey.DeleteValue("MyValue");
```